# Not zooming on the current location automatically when activity is started

Tags: android, location, zooming, android-maps

My code contains a button on a tab and by pressing the button, a map (in a fragment) is displayed on which the current location of the device is shown. along with the latitude and longitude below the map fragment. My problem is that the map is not zooming on the current location and instead displays the map on (0,0) latitude and longitude

here's my code:

```
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



    latlngText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlngText);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    getLocation();

}

void getLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    } else {

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        if (location != null) {

            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();

            latlngText.setText("Latitude: " + lat + "\n" + "Longitude: " + lng);

            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            CameraUpdate myLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 18);

            mMap.moveCamera(myLocation);

        }



    }


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    switch (requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_LOCATION:

            getLocation();

            break;


    }


}
```

Looking forward for an answer!!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-places-tutorial?hl=ko

Answer (score 0):

Try this code also I hope you add a proper dependency for map and location in-app level gradle file.

and in this demo used fausd Api for getting location update.

```
public class MapLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map Location Activity");

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapLocationActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

}

and add below permission into android manifest file ..

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```